# Motivation behind the term, "precompact."

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real Banach Spaces and let
$$
K:X\rightarrow Y
$$
be a bounded linear operator. Consider a sequence $\{u_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in $X$. We call a sequence $\{Ku_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ to be **precompact** in $Y$ if there exists a subsequence $\{u_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ such that $\{Ku_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ converges in $Y$.

**My question.** What is the significance of the name, "precompact"? I can see its similarity with the definition of sequential compactness. However, I am not able to fully comprehend (appreciate) this similarity. Could you please give me more insights into this definition and the name, "precompact"? Put simply, why is "precompact" a *good* name? By "good," I mean a name that provides some information about the entity it defines.

A more general definition is that of precompact sets (as pointed out by hal4math). A subset $E$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be precompact if its closure is compact.

Many thanks!

Comment: Where did you get that definition? It seems rather odd to me. I think it says that the image of $K$ is precompact (as I know the definition).

Comment: @hal4math This is from the book Partial Differential Equations by LC Evans. He uses it while defining a compact operator.

Comment: Hm, it does seem a bit odd to me. In any case, usually one defines what a precompact set is rather then what a precompact sequence is. Because notice that everything your definition is saying that $\{Ku_k\}$ has a convergent subsequence, or in different words, every sequence in $K(X)$ admits a convergent subsequence in $Y$. So in general, a subset $E \subset X$ is called precompact if it its closure is compact, or in sequential terms, if every sequence in $E$ admits a convergent subsequence in $X$ (!), (not $E$).

Comment: @hal4math Yeah, it makes much more sense now! Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

In the books about Banach spaces, one would often see phrases like "a subset $A$ of a Banach space $X$ is *relatively (weakly) compact*", or "$A\subset X$ is *(weakly) precompact*.

$A\subset X$ is *relatively compact* if the norm closure $\overline{A}$ is compact. $A\subset X$ is *precompact* if every sequence in $A$ has a norm Cauchy subsequence. Since a Banach space is norm-complete, the concepts *precompact* and *relatively compact* coincide.

Similarly, $A\subset X$ is *relatively weakly compact* if the weak closure $\overline{A}^w$ is weakly compact. $A\subset X$ is *weakly precompact* if every sequence in $A$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence. Every relatively weakly compact subset of $X$ is weakly precompact by Eberlein-Šmulian theorem. However, the converse is not generally true since (unlike the norm-topology) the weak topology is not sequentially complete for all Banach spaces.